# reverse geocoding incorrect result

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have a little geocoding application http://www.galerie-insecte.org/galerie/ll3.php.

The principle is rather simple: one enters some data in the entry line
above and the API gets the map and some data in the lower window
(latitude, longitude, administrative address and altitude).

Now the problem:
If I give a latlng in decimal format (43.588278,5.776472) or in DMS
format (43°35'17.8",5°46'35.3"), I get a correct map (that is, the
marker is correctly positionned [the user recognizes precisely the
spot where he took the picture]). But the latitude and longitude data
displayed is false (43.6044691,5.7687348).

More, moving the marker doesn't always change the data in the lower
window. I could not find a clear sequence to reproduce the problem
(changing to another magnification? changing to the satellite view?
both of them together?)

Does it ring a bell for any of you?

Thanks in advance.

pduhem

Answer (score 1):

Geocode service obtains the closest, human-readable address. So when you find the position of your tag from map using reverse geocode service it shows the latitude /longitude of that address only

Comment: and the second problem may be for the same reason , like if you move for shorter distances that have same human-readable address the values dont change and when you move them for longer distances they change

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you're probably hitting the nail. I had to change my code. I now use the raw latlng  returned by the geocoder.geocode (address...) call as such and I only display the street address got with geocoder.geocode (location...) call when I have the location_type ROOFTOP. If not, I only display the locality, postal code and country.
For my web site (entomology portail) it's largely enough. And the latitude and longitude data displayed is now correct.